# Can I have notification on home screen launcher icon and not only on notification Centre?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using Firebase Notifications

I can get the Notifications but I cannot get the badge on the App Icon.

According to [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), I use this part of the code in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** :

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon 
is set for incoming notification messages. -->
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
 android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

With this part of the code I can see the app icon in notification centre with the badge, but there is no badge on the home screen launcher icon.

Hope this is a silly mistake and can be fixed easy.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "main App Icon"? If you mean the home screen launcher icon, there is no badge support in Android until Android 8.0.

Comment: @CommonsWare so no badges before Android O?

Comment: Android itself has no support for launcher icon badges prior to Android 8.0. Certain home screen implementations created their own badge systems, and some of them have a documented API that you can try to use, if your app happens to be running on a device that has one of those home screens installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Shortcut Badger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) is what you are looking for.

> The ShortcutBadger makes your Android App show the count of unread messages as a badge on your App shortcut!

Anyway this will not work with some launchers (eg.: doesn't works in my Huawei Y6 II with default launcher, but it works when i use Nova launcher with TeslaUnread)

Comment: This is what I found and I wanted to double check it